# javax.sound.midi in Java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I'm trying to play some things with the javax.sound.midi ; this is the code:

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MiniMidiProject1 {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();

        Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
        Track track = seq.createTrack();

        for(int i=5;i<61;i+=4){

            track.add(makeEvent(144,1,i,100,i));
            track.add(makeEvent(128,1,i,100,i+2));
        }

        sequencer.setSequence(seq);
        sequencer.setTempoInBPM(220);
        sequencer.start();
    } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}

public static MidiEvent makeEvent(int comd, int chan, int one, int two, int tick){
    MidiEvent event = null;
    try{
        ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(comd, chan, one, two);
        event = new MidiEvent(a,tick);
    } catch(Exception a){}
    return event;
}
}
```

It's supposed to be working, because it is from the "Head First Java" book. The warning generated is:

```
??? 17, 2014 1:30:48 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

Can some one explain me what the problem is?

Comment: do you have admin privileges when running this? the code seems a WORKSFORME example...

Comment: Actually, I don't know. How can I check it?

Comment: LMGTFY http://bit.ly/UdLlSX

Comment: Yes, I have admin privileges.

Comment: Does somebody know what is the problem?